# Readtimeout/writetimeout threw an exception of type Sys.InvalidOperationException in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, vb.net-2010

I am reading data from one flat file and stored the values in to temp variable.
When get read the write the first position value from the temp I am geting read/write timeout error.

Here is my code:

```
Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
gzip = New IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress, True)
gzip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
gzip.Close()
ms.Position = 0
dim tempdata = ms.ToArray()
```

error screen print attached for more clarity.

Please help to resolve this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLnN6.png)

I tried with the below property. but no luck
ms.flush()

Comment: Post *ALL* the relevant code. Post the declaration of `buffer` and where you are assigning it data. I'm no expert on files, but it appears you're trying to write an empty `MemoryStream` from variable `ms`?